# SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: incorrect program id for instruction

Tags: spl-token, associated-token-account

I am trying to create associated token account. Token mint works fine. The error is thrown when trying to create token account.

Here's the code:

```
async function mintToken(
    connection: web3.Connection,
    payer: web3.Keypair,
    userAddress: web3.PublicKey
) {
    const tokenMint = await spl.createMint(
        connection,
        payer,
        userAddress,
        userAddress,
        8
    );
    console.log("Token mint: ", tokenMint.toBase58());

    const userTokenAddress = await spl.createAssociatedTokenAccount(
        connection,
        payer,
        tokenMint,
        userAddress,
        {
            commitment: "finalized",
        }
    );
    console.log("user token address: ", userTokenAddress.toBase58());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting up your connection like this, where it explicitly sets the commitment to "confirmed":

```
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed")
```

The issue may be that `createAssociatedTokenAccount` is getting called before the network recognizes that `tokenMint` has been created.

Alternatively, you could also try setting the "commitment" in the `createMint` function like you have with `createAssociatedTokenAccount`

Comment: This one worked thanks. I can't believe I spent hours trying to solve this issue. The error messages are vague and it's not easy to understand what the error is about.

Answer (score 0):

Which spl-token version are you using? `createAssociatedTokenAccount` seems outdated.

This is sample code for creating ATA:

```
  {
    let ata = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
      mintPubkey, // mint
      alice.publicKey, // owner
      false // allow owner off curve
    );
    console.log(`ata: ${ata.toBase58()}`);

    let tx = new Transaction();
    tx.add(
      createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
        feePayer.publicKey, // payer
        ata, // ata
        alice.publicKey, // owner
        mintPubkey // mint
      )
    );

    console.log(`create ata txhash: ${await connection.sendTransaction(tx, [feePayer])}`);
  }
```

[Docs here](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/modules.html#createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction)

Comment: I am using spl-token v0.3.6.

Comment: still getting the same error with the above code