Try to create mint and ATAaccount shows Error:Transaction simulation failed:Error processing Instruction 0:Program failed to complete
Try to create mint and ATA account, When I run anchor test, it shows Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete
here is my sol_404.ts
anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());

  const program = anchor.workspace.Sol404 as Program<Sol404>;

  const connection = new Connection("http://127.0.0.1:8899", "confirmed");
  const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection)
  
  const privateKeyJson = "/Users/brooke/.config/solana/id.json"
  const privateKeyString = fs.readFileSync(privateKeyJson, { encoding: 'utf8' });
  const privateKeyUint8Array = new Uint8Array(JSON.parse(privateKeyString));
  const admin = anchor.web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(privateKeyUint8Array);


  const [JellyTokenMintPDA] = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("jellya")],
    program.programId
  )

  const [UsdcTokenMintPDA] = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("usdc")],
    program.programId
  )

  const [NftTokenMintPDA] = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("nft")],
    program.programId
  )

  const JellyTokenAccount = spl.getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
    JellyTokenMintPDA,
    admin.publicKey
  )

  const UsdcTokenAccount = spl.getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
    UsdcTokenMintPDA,
    admin.publicKey
  )

  const NftTokenAccount = spl.getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
    NftTokenMintPDA,
    admin.publicKey
  )

  const jellymetadata = {
    uri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-developers/program-examples/new-examples/tokens/tokens/.assets/spl-token.json",
    name: "Jelly",
    symbol: "jelly",
  }

  const usdcmetadata = {
    uri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-developers/program-examples/new-examples/tokens/tokens/.assets/spl-token.json",
    name: "usdc",
    symbol: "usdc",
  }

  const nftmetadata = {
    uri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-developers/program-examples/new-examples/tokens/tokens/.assets/spl-token.json",
    name: "nft",
    symbol: "nft",
  }

  it("Is create mint!", async () => {
    const jellyTokenMintMetadataPDA = await metaplex
    .nfts()
    .pdas()
    .metadata({ mint: JellyTokenMintPDA });

    const usdcTokenMintMetadataPDA = await metaplex
    .nfts()
    .pdas()
    .metadata({ mint: UsdcTokenMintPDA });

    const nftTokenMintMetadataPDA = await metaplex
    .nfts()
    .pdas()
    .metadata({ mint: NftTokenMintPDA });

    const tx = await program.methods
    .createmint(jellymetadata.uri, usdcmetadata.uri, nftmetadata.uri, jellymetadata.name, usdcmetadata.name, nftmetadata.name, jellymetadata.symbol, usdcmetadata.symbol, nftmetadata.symbol)
    .accounts({
      admin: admin.publicKey,
      jellyTokenMint: JellyTokenMintPDA,
      usdcTokenMint: UsdcTokenMintPDA,
      nftMint: NftTokenMintPDA,
      jellyTokenAccount: JellyTokenAccount,
      usdcTokenAccount: UsdcTokenAccount,
      nftTokenAccount: NftTokenAccount,
      jellyMetadataAccount: jellyTokenMintMetadataPDA,
      usdcMetadataAccount: usdcTokenMintMetadataPDA,
      nftMetadataAccount: nftTokenMintMetadataPDA,
      tokenMetadataProgram: TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
    })
    .rpc();
    console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);
  });
});

and it is my create mint.rs
pub fn createmint(
    ctx: Context<CreateMint>,
    jelly_uri: String,
    usdc_uri: String,
    nft_uri: String,
    jelly_name: String,
    usdc_name: String,
    nft_name: String,
    jelly_symbol: String,
    usdc_symbol: String,
    nft_symbol: String,
) -> Result<()> {

    //initialize jelly mint
    let seeds = b"jellya";
    let bump = ctx.bumps.jelly_token_mint;
    let signer: &[&[&[u8]]] = &[&[seeds, &[bump]]];

    // On-chain token metadata for the mint
    let data_v2 = DataV2 {
        name: jelly_name,
        symbol: jelly_symbol,
        uri: jelly_uri,
        seller_fee_basis_points: 0,
        creators: None,
        collection: None,
        uses: None,
    };

    // CPI Context
    let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
        ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
        CreateMetadataAccountsV3 {
            metadata: ctx.accounts.jelly_metadata_account.to_account_info(), // the metadata account being created
            mint: ctx.accounts.jelly_token_mint.to_account_info(), // the mint account of the metadata account
            mint_authority: ctx.accounts.jelly_token_mint.to_account_info(), // the mint authority of the mint account
            update_authority: ctx.accounts.jelly_token_mint.to_account_info(), // the update authority of the metadata account
            payer: ctx.accounts.admin.to_account_info(), // the payer for creating the metadata account
            system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(), // the system program account, required when creating new accounts
            rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(), // the rent sysvar account
        },
        signer, // pda signer
    );

    create_metadata_accounts_v3(
        cpi_ctx, // cpi context
        data_v2, // token metadata
        true,    // is_mutable
        true,    // update_authority_is_signer
        None,    // collection details
    )?;


    //initialize usdc mint
    let seeds = b"usdc";
    let bump = ctx.bumps.usdc_token_mint;
    let signer: &[&[&[u8]]] = &[&[seeds, &[bump]]];

    // CPI Context
    let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
        ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
        CreateMetadataAccountsV3 {
            metadata: ctx.accounts.usdc_metadata_account.to_account_info(), // the metadata account being created
            mint: ctx.accounts.usdc_token_mint.to_account_info(), // the mint account of the metadata account
            mint_authority: ctx.accounts.usdc_token_mint.to_account_info(), // the mint authority of the mint account
            update_authority: ctx.accounts.usdc_token_mint.to_account_info(), // the update authority of the metadata account
            payer: ctx.accounts.admin.to_account_info(), // the payer for creating the metadata account
            system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(), // the system program account, required when creating new accounts
            rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(), // the rent sysvar account
        },
        signer, // pda signer
    );

    let data_v2 = DataV2 {
        name: usdc_name,
        symbol: usdc_symbol,
        uri: usdc_uri,
        seller_fee_basis_points: 0,
        creators: None,
        collection: None,
        uses: None,
    };

    create_metadata_accounts_v3(
        cpi_ctx, // cpi context
        data_v2, // token metadata
        true,    // is_mutable
        true,    // update_authority_is_signer
        None,    // collection details
    )?;

  

    let seeds = b"nft";
    let bump = ctx.bumps.nft_mint;
    let signer: &[&[&[u8]]] = &[&[seeds, &[bump]]];

    let data_v2 = DataV2 {
        name: nft_name,
        symbol: nft_symbol,
        uri: nft_uri,
        seller_fee_basis_points: 0,
        creators: None,
        collection: None,
        uses: None,
    };

     // CPI Context
     let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
        ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
        CreateMetadataAccountsV3 {
            metadata: ctx.accounts.nft_metadata_account.to_account_info(), // the metadata account being created
            mint: ctx.accounts.nft_mint.to_account_info(), // the mint account of the metadata account
            mint_authority: ctx.accounts.nft_mint.to_account_info(), // the mint authority of the mint account
            update_authority: ctx.accounts.nft_mint.to_account_info(), // the update authority of the metadata account
            payer: ctx.accounts.admin.to_account_info(), // the payer for creating the metadata account
            system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(), // the system program account, required when creating new accounts
            rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(), // the rent sysvar account
        },
        signer, // pda signer
    );

    create_metadata_accounts_v3(
        cpi_ctx, // cpi context
        data_v2, // token metadata
        true,    // is_mutable
        true,    // update_authority_is_signer
        None,    // collection details
    )?;


    Ok(())
}


#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateMint<'info> {
    // Use ADMIN_PUBKEY as constraint, only the specified admin can invoke this instruction
    #[account(
        mut,
        address = ADMIN_PUBKEY
    )]
    pub admin: Signer<'info>,

    // The PDA is both the address of the mint account and the mint authority
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"jellya"],
        bump,
        payer = admin,
        mint::decimals = 9,
        mint::authority = jelly_token_mint,
    )]
    pub jelly_token_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    
    ///CHECK: Using "address" constraint to validate metadata account address, this account is created via CPI in the instruction
    #[account(
        mut,
        address = MetadataAccount::find_pda(&jelly_token_mint.key()).0,
    )]
    pub jelly_metadata_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"usdc"],
        bump,
        payer = admin,
        mint::decimals = 9,
        mint::authority = usdc_token_mint,
    )]
    pub usdc_token_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        address = MetadataAccount::find_pda(&usdc_token_mint.key()).0,
    )]
    /// CHECK: The `usdc_metadata_account` is an UncheckedAccount, which means that no runtime safety checks
    pub usdc_metadata_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    // nft mint
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"nft"],
        bump,
        payer = admin,
        mint::decimals = 0,
        mint::authority = nft_mint,
    )]
    pub nft_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        address = MetadataAccount::find_pda(&nft_mint.key()).0,
    )]
    /// CHECK: The `usdc_metadata_account` is an UncheckedAccount, which means that no runtime safety checks
    pub nft_metadata_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = admin,
        associated_token::mint = jelly_token_mint,
        associated_token::authority = admin,
    )]
    pub jelly_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = admin,
        associated_token::mint = usdc_token_mint,
        associated_token::authority = admin,
    )]
    pub usdc_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = admin,
        associated_token::mint = nft_mint,
        associated_token::authority = admin,
    )]
    pub nft_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub token_metadata_program: Program<'info, Metadata>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}


I tried to change the connection according to another problem in here https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6407/sendtransactionerror-failed-to-send-transaction-transaction-simulation-failed , but don't work.

Program failed to complete typically means that your program crashed or ran out of compute units, so be sure to check the logs of your program to see what exactly happened
